# Simultaneous Ctrl_L+Shift layout switch doesn't operate as before

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, 15.04, keyboard-layout, gnome-tweak-tool

After using gnome-tweak-tool on my 15.04 with Unity the keyboard layout switch (<kbd>Ctrl L</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>) doesn't work as before.

Now I always have to complete the exact sequence: **press <kbd>Shift</kbd> first and hold it, then press <kbd>Ctrl L</kbd>**.

**Simultaneous <kbd>Ctrl_L</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>** doesn't work anymore and I don't know how to get it back.

Even custom setting of layout switch to "Ctrl L+Shift" doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling **Show location of pointer** at Mouse section of gnome-tweak-tool changing the **Ctrl+Shift** behavior to that I described in my question.

Disabling this feature restores normal behavior for this shortcut.